# String array in C has the newest value for all indices

Tags: arrays, c, string, list

I'm having an issue with storing strings in a `**char` array in C.

It appears that for an `int` array, when assigning a value to an index by using `int_arr[idx] = 2`, the previous indices retain the correct value.

For a string array `char *str_arr[]`, if I do a similar assignment of `str_arr[idx] = "hello"`, all previous indices also get assigned that value

The snippet of code below + output shows the issue:

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 10

void print_string_arr( char **arr )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++ )
    {
        printf("%s, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void print_int_arr( int *arr )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    // String array
    char *str_arr[MAX_LENGTH] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        char tmp[MAX_LENGTH];
        // Convert int to str
        sprintf(tmp, "%d", i);
        str_arr[i] = tmp;
        print_string_arr(str_arr);
    }

    printf("\n");

    // Integer array
    int int_arr[MAX_LENGTH] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        int_arr[i] = i;
        print_int_arr(int_arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
String array:
0, (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), 
1, 1, (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), 
2, 2, 2, (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), 
3, 3, 3, 3, (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, (null), (null), (null), (null), 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, (null), (null), (null), 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, (null), (null), 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, (null), 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 

Integer array:
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```

I'm unsure as to why this happens and how to fix it - would really appreciate a concise explanation as to why this happens so that I could learn to avoid it in future applications.

Comment: It's not that they all have the same string, but the same string *pointer*. The actual string array gets overwritten. The `str_arr[i] = tmp;` copies a pointer.

Comment: Not only that, but the string array `char tmp[MAX_LENGTH];` pointed to has gone **out of scope** by the time you report the results.

Answer (score 1):

The array `char tmp[MAX_LENGTH];` is non-static and local to its scope. This means it will vanish when exiting from the scope and newly created again on entering the scope again (in the next iteration of the loop).

Therefore, assigning a pointer to the array like `str_arr[i] = tmp;` is useless.
You should copy the string and assign a pointer to the copy instead.

If [`strdup()`] is supported in your system:

```
#include <string.h>

...

str_arr[i] = strdup(tmp);
```

If it is not supported or you want to use only standard functions:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

...

str_arr[i] = malloc(strlen(tmp) + 1); /* +1 for terminating null-character */
if (str_arr[i] == NULL) exit(1); /* check if allocation succeeded */
strcpy(str_arr[i], tmp);
```